# refreshing web page using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to refresh only the current web page using powershell.But all the opened web pages are being refreshed.My code is here

```
   function Refresh-WebPages {
        param(
            $interval = 5
        )
        "Refreshing IE Windows every $interval seconds."
        "Press any key to stop."
        $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
        do {
            'Refreshing ALL HTML'
            $shell.Windows() | 
                Where-Object { $_.Document.url } | 
                ForEach-Object { $_.Refresh() }
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $interval
        } until ( [System.Console]::KeyAvailable )
        [System.Console]::ReadKey($true) | Out-Null
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `Where` clause which filters out all windows with `.url`

```
Where-Object { $_.Document.url }
```

All you would need to do is refine that for the specific url you are looking for.

```
Where-Object { $_.Document.url -like 'http://google*' }
```

That would filter out all the pages that start with `http://google`. If there is a more elegant solution for targeting one page I am not aware of it.