# Refreshing webpage on firefox with powershell

Tags: powershell

hope you're all doing well today, let me put my mask and explain you my issue :

I want to use powershell to refresh a webpage every 5/10s, I think it's possible as I found this : [refreshing web page using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888915/refreshing-web-page-using-powershell)

I tried to change the URL but it don't work at all...

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: This will only work in IE sadly. I doubt it's possible in FF at all.

Comment: On edge you think it's possiblle ?

Comment: What are you [really trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)? Find out if page contents are changing? Stress testing? Something else?